# how to wrap an objective-c interface implementing two protocols in Monotouch

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

I have an interface that implements two protocols in objective-C and I want to wrap it in Monotouch.

```
@interface GDExtended : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,GDiOSDelegate>
- (void) handleEvent:(GDAppEvent *)anEvent; 
@end
```

The required method `HandleEvent` belongs to GDiOS protocol but it needs `UIApplicationDelegate` in order to communicate with the view.

The problem is that when I extend this class in sample app in Monotouch I get an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`

*Reason:* `AppDelegate` (the name that the class is registered with) does not implement `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !!

Comment: `AppDelegate` is created by default as the application delegate. If you're creating your own class named `AppDelegate` then there may be a conflict.

Comment: The class that inherits the GDEnhanced (which is the wrapped interface) is defined as follows :                             [Register ("AppDelegate")]
Public partial class AppDelegate : GDEnhanced {...}

Comment: This class is part of BubbleCell sample project

Comment: Does `AppDelegate` implement `UIApplicationDelegate` in its header?

Comment: AppDelegate implements GDExtended (GDExtended implements UIApplicationDelegate).                                                  [register ("AppDelegate")]                                       public partial class AppDelegate : GDExtended { ... }

Comment: Just have `AppDelegate` implement `UIApplicationDelegate` and see if you get errors.

Comment: But when I do that I cannot override the event handler method of GDiOSDelegate.

Comment: Copy all of the GDExtended stuff into your app delegate